How to apply classes to the checkboxes that are rendered in a buefy b-table when checkable is set to true?
I have a buefy b-table component and I'm trying to style the checkboxes to match the rest of my project by applying classes to them. Since I am not actually creating/rendering the element, how do I access it to apply the class?
I tried using:
checkboxType= "my-custom-class"
But that didn't work. I tried accessing the checkboxes via refs after they were rendered and adding classes like this:
this.$nextTick(() =>{
               const checkboxes = this.$refs.tableComponent.$el.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
               checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
                   checkbox.classList.add('my-custom-class');
               })
           })

Any advice is appreciated!

Why not use a CSS selector here rather than JS?

How would I do that? Can you be a bit more specific?

@user456 Add a specific class to tableComponent and define styles for .my-table input[type="checkbox"] {...}

So my table has class="my-table". Then in my table.scss file I target the input via input[type="checkbox"]{ @extend .my-custom-class;} This should work?

@user456 Yes, should be like that. The selector should be .my-table input[type="checkbox"] to not affect other inputs

Has this worked with the b-table checkboxes in your experience? I haven't been able to get this to work either.

Overall, this is a CSS issue mostly, unrelated to Vue.js or Bulma. Hence you can try to solve it in a more simple playground like Codepen.

I have been trying to use css selectors but I just can't get it to work right because I'm not actually rendering the checkboxes, so can't apply a class to them. Unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Are the checkboxes in the DOM? Why would you apply a class to something you do not render? What is the end goal? Query selector or any other kind also does not apply to something not in the DOM more than CSS selector.
